# No query results for model , Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I try to delete a record from 2 tables, both records exist, but I got an error, and I am not sure why.

```
public function destroy(Person $id, $personId)
{
    try {
        $people = Person::find($personId);
        $people->delete();

        $register = Register::find($id->id);
        $register->delete();
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        report($exception);
        return response($exception->getMessage(), 404);
    }

    return response('Deleted');
}

Route::delete('/record/{id}/{personId}', 'PersonController@destroy');
```

In Person table,I have FK key for register_id ,and the relationship is made.

> "No query results for model [App\Person] 15676"

Comment: what is the difference between $id and $personId?

Comment: plz post the route code.

Comment: I'm just assume, when you delete `$people`, what `id` is it? is it `15676`?

Comment: The naming is not really good. $id is registers ID, and $personID is people's id.

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: It won't work like that. You type hinted the model of the $id to be of the Person class and that's what you'll get. You could change it to be '/record/{record}/{person}' and in controller Person $person, Record $record. You won't have to fetch them again yourself, Laravel will take care of that. Just check whether the variables are empty

Comment: I just find a solution. "  $people->register->delete(); " , insted of $register....I will make some more testes, but seems to work.

Comment: update your table details...

Comment: The relationship between people- -> register is made correctly ,(both in model / migrations). This seems to be the Laravel way of deleting from table with relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query and try it like :

```
$people =Person::where('id',$personId)->delete();
$register =Register::where('id',$id)->delete(); // not sure update_id is `$id`
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer:  , this is what I get .